# Generic repository with pagination

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, pagination

I'm having trouble getting this method to work generically. My objective is to create a generic function using Entity Framework (EF) that can search the database with filters, includes, and pagination.

My difficulty lies in the filters. I would like to analyze each type of variable; for example, filtering strings only if they are different from null or empty, guids when they are different from Guid.Empty, and so on.

```
        public virtual async Task<PageFilter<TEntity>> GetWithFilterAndPagination(
            BaseRequestFilter pagination,
            List<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>> includes,
            List<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>> filters)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var dbContext = IntegramillDbContextFactory.Create())
                {
                    var query = dbContext.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();

                    if (includes != null && includes.Any())
                    {
                        foreach (var include in includes)
                        {
                            query = query.Include(include);
                        }
                    }

                    if (filters != null && filters.Any())
                    {
                        foreach (var filter in filters)
                        {
                            query = query.Where(filter);
                        }
                    }

                    var totalCount = query.Count();
                    if (pagination.Offset != null)
                        query = query.Skip((int)pagination.Offset);

                    if (pagination.Take > 0)
                        query = query.Take(pagination.Take);

                    return new PageFilter<TEntity>(query.ToList(), totalCount);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Error(e, "<{EventoId}> - Erro ao CONSULTAR " + typeof(TEntity).Name, "RepositoryError");
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

I already tried this but not works properly

```
                            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "x");
                            var expressaoBinaria = (BinaryExpression)filter.Body;
                            var propriedade = (MemberExpression)expressaoBinaria.Left;
                            var valor = expressaoBinaria.Right.ToObject();
                            var valor2 = expressaoBinaria.Right.ToString();
                            var valor3 = (MemberExpression)expressaoBinaria.Right;
                            var tipoDaPropriedade = propriedade.Type;

                            if (tipoDaPropriedade == typeof(string))
                            {
                                var teste2 = (string)valor2;
                                await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("testeString");
                            }
                            if (tipoDaPropriedade == typeof(int))
                            {
                                var teste2 = int.Parse(valor2);
                                await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("teste");
                            }
```

Comment: To clarify: if someone passes in `x => x.Name == name` as a filter, and `name` happens to be a null or empty string, you want to exclude that filter? That sounds very problematic: what if there's a property where null means something important (`item.DeletedDate == null`)? What if the expression isn't a simple binary expression? The generic repository should avoid making specific assumptions about the intent of the arguments it's given. Let the people writing the calling code check whether `name` is null before including that filter.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, In this case, these filters are those passed through the front-end, so only string values ​​that have values ​​are considered, such as name, title of something, there is no need to filter null values

Comment: Typically the front-end provides a simpler model (something serializable, not involving `Expression` trees), and then a layer that translates that model into expression trees for things like Sort and Filter. That layer is where I would ignore filters with empty/null values. When you decide to add features to the front-end to let people do more advanced filters "contains(x)", "is blank/not blank", etc., it'll be much easier to do with a limited, well-defined model than trying to comprehend arbitrary Expression trees.

Comment: I understood, but I wanted to set up the most generic repository possible to be able to use it in several places in the application without many adjustments, as the architecture of my project is divided into layers, I should do this part of the logic in the service layer, but then I would have I have to do this logic for each service, this way it ends up deviating from my initial idea

Answer (score 0):

Given these extension methods:

```
public static class StringExt {
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this string s) => String.IsNullOrEmpty(s);
}

public static class ExpressionExt {
    public static TResult Value<TResult>(this Expression e) => (TResult)((e is ConstantExpression c) ? c.Value : Expression.Lambda(e).Compile().DynamicInvoke());
}
```

You can test the RHS of the filter with something like:

```
var r = (filter.Body as BinaryExpression)?.Right;
var t = r?.Type;

if (t == typeof(string) && !r.Value<string>().IsNullOrEmpty())
    q = q.Where(filter);
else if (t == typeof(Guid) && r.Value<Guid>() != Guid.Empty)
    q = q.Where(filter);
```

Note that if the filter is not in the expected format (e.g. a lambda with a simple binary expression with the LHS being the parameter), then it will just be ignored.

Also not that this is unlikely to be very fast, as it is using `LambdaExpression.Compile()` to compute the value of the RHS when it is not a constant.